# How to Creating a Custom Product Type in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product-type, affiliate

How to create a Custom product type by default.

It like Affiliate Products.

Comment: The extension name is AffiliateProduct:
Please check it @ http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/creating-a-custom-product-type-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

You add below code in your etc.xml file

```
<catalog>
            <product>
                <type>
                    <affilated translate="label" module="affilatedproduct">
                        <label>Affilated Product</label>
                        <model>affilatedproduct/product_type</model>
                        <price_model>affilatedproduct/product_price</price_model>
                        <is_qty>0</is_qty>
                        <composite>0</composite>
                        <index_priority>20</index_priority>
                        <can_use_qty_decimals>0</can_use_qty_decimals>
                    </affilated>
                </type>
            </product>
        </catalog>
```

in Model_Product_Type file

```
class Vendor_Affilatedproduct_Model_Product_Type extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract
{
    const TYPE_AFFILIATE          = 'affilated';
    const XML_PATH_AUTHENTICATION = 'catalog/affilated/authentication';
    protected function _prepareProduct(Varien_Object $buyRequest, $product, $processMode)
    {  
        if ($this->_isStrictProcessMode($processMode)) {
            return Mage::helper('affilatedproduct')->__(
                'Affiliate product %s cannot be added to cart. ' .
                ' On the product detail page click the "Go to parent site"'.
                ' button to access the product.',
                $product->getName()
            );
        }
        return parent::_prepareProduct($buyRequest, $product, $processMode);
    }
}
```